# How to do this in R

Tags: r, calculation

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
groups <- c(1:20)
A <- c(1,3,2,4,2,5,1,6,2,7,3,5,2,6,3,5,1,5,3,4)
B <- c(3,2,4,1,5,2,4,1,3,2,6,1,4,2,5,3,7,1,4,2)
position <- c(2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1)
sample.data <- data.frame(groups,A,B,position)
head(sample.data)
      groups     A       B     position
  1      1       1       3        2
  2      2       3       2        1
  3      3       2       4        2
  4      4       4       1        1
  5      5       2       5        2
  6      6       5       2        1
```

The "position" column always alternates between 2 and 1. I want to do this calculation in R: starting from the first row, if it's in position 1, ignore it. If it starts at 2 (as in this example), then calculate as follows:

- Take the first 2 values of column A that are at position 2, average them, then subtract the first value that is at position 1 (in this example: (1+2)/2 - 3 = -1.5). Then repeat the calculation for the next set of values, using the last position 2 value as the starting point, i.e. the next calculation would be (2+2)/2 - 4 = -2.
- So basically, in this example, the calculations are done for the values of these sets of groups: 1-2-3, 3-4-5, 5-6-7, etc. (the last value of the previous is the first value of the next set of calculation)
- Repeat the calculation until the end. Also do the same for column B.
- Since I need the original data frame intact, put the newly calculated values in a new data frame(s), with columns dA and dB corresponding to the calculated values of column A and B, respectively (if not possible then they can be created as separated data frames, and I will extract them into one afterwards).

Desired output (from the example):

```
    dA    dB
1  -1.5  1.5
2   -2   3.5
3  -3.5  2.5
4  -4.5  2.5
5  -4.5  2.5
6  -2.5   4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
groups <- c(1:20)
A <- c(1,3,2,4,2,5,1,6,2,7,3,5,2,6,3,5,1,5,3,4)
B <- c(3,2,4,1,5,2,4,1,3,2,6,1,4,2,5,3,7,1,4,2)
position <- c(2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1)
sample.data <- data.frame(groups,A,B,position)

start <- match(2, sample.data$position)
twos <- seq(from = start, to = nrow(sample.data), by = 2)

df <- 
  sapply(c("A", "B"), function(l) {
    sapply(twos, function(i) { 
      mean(sample.data[c(i, i+2), l]) - sample.data[i+1, l]
    })
  })

df <- setNames(as.data.frame(df), c('dA', 'dB'))
```

Answer (score 1):

As your values in `position` always alternate between 1 and 2, you can define an index of odd rows `i1` and an index of even rows `i2`, and do your calculations:

```
## In case first row has position==1, we add an increment of 1 to the indexes
inc=0
if(sample.data$position[1]==1)
{inc=1}
i1=seq(1+inc,nrow(sample.data),by=2)
i2=seq(2+inc,nrow(sample.data),by=2)
res=data.frame(dA=(lead(sample.data$A[i1])+sample.data$A[i1])/2-sample.data$A[i2],
dB=(lead(sample.data$B[i1])+sample.data$B[i1])/2-sample.data$B[i2]);
```

This returns:

```
dA  dB
1  -1.5 1.5
2  -2.0 3.5
3  -3.5 2.5
4  -4.5 2.5
5  -4.5 2.5
6  -2.5 4.0
7  -3.5 2.5
8  -3.0 3.0
9  -3.0 4.5
10   NA  NA
```

The last row returns NA, you can remove it if you need.

```
res=na.omit(res)
```

Comment: I noticed that in your code, the `if` statement starts with "if the first position is 2". What happens if the sample starts at position 1? Will it ignore the first row, or will it not  work? Thanks

Comment: I thought you wanted to do the calculations only if the first row contained 2. But maybe you want to do the calculations starting from the first row that contains 2, and if the first row contains 1, leave it unchanged, is that right? I've changed the answer to reflect that.

Comment: yes, sorry about the confusion. Perhaps I should have said "ignore the first row", not "ignore it". If the data starts at position 1, then just leave that row, and perform the calculation starting from the first row of position 2 (which is the next one). P.S. I haven't seen the changes, have you saved the edit, or are still editting? Thanks

Comment: I think I understand now what you wanted. I've edited the answer.